# Including a Modal in a Backbone View

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

i'm trying to include a Modal, specifically this one: http://awkward.github.io/backbone.modal/ for each one of the models in a collection.

First i tried with a handlebars template, but it didn't work i don't know if it is for using _underscore so i change but i can't see why is not working.

Here is my function that use in the View that executes on a click for a rendered model:

```
detalleProducto : function(event){
        var id = $(event.currentTarget).data('id');
        var item = this.collection.get(id);

        var templt = _.template("<div class='bbm-modal__topbar'>\
                <h3 class='bbm-modal__title'> <%= item.nombre %> </h3>\
            </div>\
            <div class='bbm-modal__section'>\
                <img src='img/modal/ <%= item.imagen %>' />\
                <p><%= item.descripcion %></p>\
                <p><%= item.presentacion %></p>\
            </div>\
            <div class='bbm-modal__bottombar'>\
            <a href='#' class='bbm-button'>Close</a>\
            </div>"
        );
        var tmpl = templt({item: item.attributes}); 

        var Modal = Backbone.Modal.extend({
            template: tmpl,
            cancelEl: '.bbm-button'
        });

        var modalView = new Modal();
        $('#app').html(modalView.render().el);

    },
```

In the console says me Uncaught TypeError: Property 'template' of object [object Object] is not a function.

So, maybe im not passing the template correctly??
I appreciate all or your help.
Thanx...

Comment: Do all of the properties of `item` exist? I played with your code, and the template rendered for me.

Comment: @EmptyArsenal did you see the Modal?? and yes...all the items properties exists...

Comment: If it's complaining about the line with `var templt = _.template(...)`, it may be that `_` has not finished loading, so it can't call the `template` function inside it.